# What exactly do くれ and と mean in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I am reading the novel 『狐霊の檻』 by 廣嶋玲子. In the beginning the narrator describes a feast she had once taken part in. She says

> 好きなだけ飲んでくれと、庭に置かれた酒の大樽【おおだる】。

I think that the sentence means something like

> *In the garden there was a cask of sake from which we drank whenever we wanted.*

But I do not understand the grammatical functions of くれ and と.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

～てくれ is an imperative form that's stronger than ～てください or ～て, but a little weaker than the plain imperative (飲め). と here is the same quotative と as in ～という. You can think of this sentence as saying something like

> 好きなだけ飲んでくれ**と言っているかのように**、庭に置かれた酒の大樽

> There was a cask of spirits in the garden, *as if they were telling us* to drink as much as we like.

Note that this is not grammatically an abbreviation, I believe. Additionally 酒 can refer to any alcoholic drink and not just the one we call sake in English (日本酒).